# Which date time format is this?

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, zendesk

I wonder which format is the following datetime value:

> "2016-05-18T12:05:33Z"

This date time format is used on Zendesk's [tickets](https://developer.zendesk.com/rest_api/docs/core/tickets) in the fields of created_at and updated_at.

I know that its "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss........", but what does the "Z" stand for?

What I want to do is parse and convert into a java.time class for storing dates and times, but I do not know which is the best one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format and the `Z` is the timezone indicator; it means UTC.

The best `java.time` class to use is `ZonedDateTime`. Example:

```
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2016-05-18T12:05:33Z",
                                             DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME);
```